# View only DEBUG log entries in Visual Studio Code when using Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

When using Visual Studio Code and Salesforce DX palette command:

```
SFDX Get Apex debug logs...
```

To get an Apex Log from the Salesforce servers, how can I then filter the output so I can only see the DEBUG statements? (like in the developer console).

Comment: See if the approach of using an extension for this works for you. I've explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174681/how-to-highlight-user-specified-words-in-vscode Notice the |DEBUG| keyword is in every user debug line of the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this in the VSCode terminal and the debug logs will be rendered there for you when you run your unit tests, etc.

```
sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | grep --line-buffered "USER_DEBUG"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use **Logpoints** feature of debugger instead of USER_DEBUG (system.debug).

Reference:

- [Visual Studio Code: Debugging: Logpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_logpoints)

Comment: Can someone verify this works?

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me (insert into cmd):

`sfdx force:apex:execute -f "<myfilewithsystemdebug>" | grep --line-buffered "USER_DEBUG"`