# `sfdx force:apex:log:tail` to only show [USER_DEBUG] logs not working

Tags: salesforcedx, debugging, visualstudiocode, debug-logs

I'm connected to a Playground org in VS Code.

I have made and deployed a class to this org and would like to run some anonymous code in VS Code to test a method of the class.

I was able to do this by **Ctrl + Shift + P** and **SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents**. However, the output is too verbose:

[image]

...whereas I would like to view `|USER_DEBUG|` entries only.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/348292/123882) suggests using `sfdx force:apex:log:tail` (since I'm on Windows, I had to use `findstr` instead of `grep`), but got the following error:

[image]

I also tried using the `--loglevel` argument instead of `grep` and got the same error:

[image]

But when I supply my username, nothing happens - the prompt just hangs:

[image]

When I press **Ctrl + C**, it asks me if I want to `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`

**Could it be because I'm using a Playground org instead of a scratch org?**

---

EDIT: I tried running it in the VS Code terminal to no avail:

[image]

Comment: You need to be either in a project workspace with a default username set, a global default username set, or specified with the `-u` argument. It appears you're in your home directory, which typically wouldn't be a suitable place for development.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, so I should first navigate to my project directory before running the command? I tried that with `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\VSCodeQuickStart> sfdx force:apex:log:tail -u <myusername> --loglevel=debug`, but it just hangs again. I'm not sure about the default username. The default username in my project's `.sfdx-config.json` is set to "vscodeOrg", but running `sfdx force:apex:log:tail -u vscodeOrg --loglevel=debug` doesn't work.

Comment: @sfdcfox, is there any other way to suppress non-USER_DEBUG output?

Comment: @user135792 do you have a solution in the meantime? I'm facing the same issue...