# Is sfdx force:apex:log:tail working with findstr on Windows 10?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

As I'm on Windows 10 and currently not intending to install the Linux Subsystem (WSL) on my machine I'm wondering why I couldn't get this command running `sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | findstr USER_DEBUG` - it simply generates no output whereas `sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color` is working as expected. I also found this question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388828/sfdx-forceapexlogtail-to-only-show-user-debug-logs-not-working) which isn't answering it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That command worked for me in Windows 10.
Some suggestions for the SFDX command:
I used the -u flag to specify the org
I used the -d flag to specify a custom logging level

Within findstr, I used /c:”USER_DEBUG”, although it also worked without the extra syntax.

Note that after hitting ‘enter’ in the command console, the command console will appear to hang until a log is created. I executed an Apex test method from the Salesforce browser UI. When the Apex test finished, the command console displayed the lines that contained “USER_DEBUG”

Also, I occasionally saw errors from findstr saying that a line was too long.

Comment: Didn't worked for me- in the meantime I moved from [sfdx (v7) to sf (v2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_move_to_sf_v2.htm) the new command is then `sfdx apex log tail --color -d DEV_DEBUG -o Org | findstr /c:"USER_DEBUG"` but same result - no logs...

Comment: additional question: is it common, that you get a `Socket timeout occurred while listening for results.` after a few minutes idle? (while using the command without `findstr`)

Comment: What is the action you are taking in Salesforce that would be logged? I executed an Apex test, and saw the ‘USER_DEBUG’ output moments after the test completed.
Also, for a simple test of the command, it would be best if the SFDX user is the same as logged in user in Salesforce that you are generating the log for.

Comment: I'm also running only Apex tests, user should be the same... strange. Could it be related to Windows itself? I will do some investigation here...

Comment: I have no idea... surprisingly today I once got the `findstr` output never then again... simply no idea...

Comment: Short update: I updated PowerShell to version 7.3.6 - and it's no working as expected on my Windows 10 system.